# VB6 Memory leak from Interop object

Tags: vb6, activex, com-interop

I have an activeX interop control that is used in an old VB6 application. The ActiveX control is a gridview component and it loads a few hundred thousand records, eating up approx 300MB of Memory every time its started.

Eventually VB runs out of memory.

The interop control is referenced like a normal activex control and loaded using the following code

```
dim withevents gridview as vbcontrolextender
dim withevents uv as applicationlistcontrol.appgrid
dim imc as applicationlistcontrol.iappgrid

private sub form_load

set gridview = Controls.Add("Applicationlistcontrol.appgrid", "ApplicationListView", me)
set uv = gridview.Control
set imc = uv
imc.FillGrid '(Calls the C# control and loads data into grid)
end sub

private sub form_unload
set imc = nothing
set uv = nothing 
set gridview = nothing 
end sub
```

The memory is also kept when exiting the application and returning to VB6 IDE and next time its started, another 300 MB get chewed up.

This is the function that loads the data:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) 
{ 
    connection.Open(); 
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM APPLICATION_LIST WHERE APPLICATION_TYPE_ID = 1", connection)) 
    { 
        using (var table = new DataTable()) 
        { 
            table.Load(command.ExecuteReader()); 
        } 
    } 
} 

GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(); 
return null;
```

Comment: Does the control have some sort of a `.Dispose()` method?

Comment: Just in test mode now. But I can add whatever I want.

Comment: If you have written this component and have control over the source code, you should add the source code here. Try to make the smallest possible complete code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @siwix FYI I added the code from your comment to the Q so I could read it; but in future you can actually edit the Q yourself to do that.

Comment: For testing purposes the GC calls can be useful if they are in the right place. But I don' think that is the right place :)  You would want to call them once the memory allocated for the control is no longer needed - but it seems like it is still needed in the code you posted. Call that basically at the end of `form_unload`. You might need to add a temporary method just to do that.  Also, you may need a second `GC.Collect()` call following `WaitForFullGCComplete`